# how does vim distinguish ESC key from the header of escape sequence?

Tags: linux, vim, terminal

When we press `home` key, vim receives three ascii code: \e O H.

How does vim determine that the user pressed `home`, rather than pressed `Esc` `O` `H`.

One approach I thought of is: read() the stdin with a large *count* argument  to drain it, test the return value. If larger than 1, we think it's an escape sequence generated by a function key.

However, there is a problem: 
If vim ran on a remote server, and the user operated it through putty. The user wanted  to insert a line above and insert a character `H`, so he pressed `Esc` `O` `H`. The three keystrokes were wrapped into three net packages and transferred to server. These packages arrived at the same time due to network congestion.
Thus, these three characters appeared in the stdin buffer of vim at the same time, and were mistaken as an escape sequence of `home`.

I don't know how vim avoids such problem, and do you have a better approach?

Comment: Vim guesses based on (configurable) timing parameters. See `:h 'timeout`, `:h 'ttimeout`, `:h 'tm`, `:h 'ttm`.

Comment: You can read vim source or a simple editor kilo at https://github.com/antirez/kilo/blob/master/kilo.c

Comment: So putty also transfers keystrokes time intervals, I guess?

Comment: @weiweishuo What do you mean?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww I think you will be satisfied immediately if I change the title to "How should I distinguish ..".

Comment: Following up on @JoyAllen's comment - kilo [sets a 100ms timeout](https://github.com/antirez/kilo/blob/efd541bb6d272f953e049a85d411765eed1a2979/kilo.c#L225) and [tries to read an extra character after ESC](https://github.com/antirez/kilo/blob/efd541bb6d272f953e049a85d411765eed1a2979/kilo.c#L249).

Answer (score 2):

melpomene already pointed to the relevant `vim` help topics regarding `timeout`.

> So putty also transfers keystrokes time intervals, I guess?

No, `putty` doesn't do such a thing. `vim` can only regard the time intervals between its reception of the characters of a key sequence, and exactly that's the reason why several characters can be inadvertently interpreted as a control sequence if they are typed in too quick succession, or contracted by the transmission.